# Changing date format from day of year format (DDDYYYY) to Date Format (MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to convert data thats in DDDYYYY (i.e. 1112014) to a standard date format (Feb-02-2014). How would i go about doing this? I know how to do the inverse operation but I was unable to find any examples online of how to convert from DDDYYYY format to MM/DD/YYYY format.

Below is my attempt:

```
select to_date(to_char(1112018, 'DDDYYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;
```

Comment: So, the input is a string and the output also a string? Don't you need to take the input (which should be `'1112018'`, with the single-quotes) and make it into a date, so use `to_date` on it (not `to_char`!), and then take the result and make it into a string (so use `to_char` on the result of the first function, not `to_date`)? If the input is really a number and not a string, then you should use `TO_CHAR(..., '0000000')` on it first - I just hope it's not a number!

Comment: Replace your to_date with to_char and to_char with to_date. I hope this is a home work.

Comment: thanks! and what if it isn't homework :( is that bad.

Comment: It's bad if you have dates stored in string data type. Is that the case?

Comment: how is your date stored in Oracle? Is it stored as a DATE? If not....sigh.

Comment: yes... i didn't design it this way by the way!